# React, how do not loose focus on element when click outside using ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, blur, onfocus

I have a component, where I focus on component I need not to loose focus when I focus my cursor on browsers address bar or go to another window. I use react 16.3. Also I see some error [image]

```
export class Automatic extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => this.focusContainer()
    componentDidUpdate = () => this.focusContainer()

    focusContainer = () => this.refs.container.focus()


    render = () => {
           return (
            <div
                name='automatic'
                style={{outline: 'none'}}
                onKeyPress={this.captureInput}
                onBlur={this.focusContainer}
                ref='container'
                tabIndex={0}
            >
                ....
            </div>)
}
```

Also I try to use new api `React.createRef();` it also does not work, actyally this `div` is a child of some modal window

Comment: why are you focussing on blur? I can imagine this creates some kind of infinite loop / stack overflow. try to remove it.

Comment: actually I need always focus untill this div is active, even we onblur and loose focus I still need kepp focus

Comment: "where I focus on component I need not to loose focus when I focus my cursor on browsers address bar or go to another window". I don't think this is possible.

Comment: i think you have to make your intention clearer. IMHO technically it makes no sense to focus an element on blur.

Comment: I agree with comments above. Just nicely display a warning message if you really want user to focus on some field. For example: "You must provide this field value"

Comment: Actually I have a barcode scanner  device and during scanning I'm showing some image for user in modal window 'Please scan' - I do not have any input field to type value. looks like it is not possible to keep focus until finish scanning